# Soldering my own CUL sender/receiver

Tags: schematics, home-automation

I have been thinking of starting a new home project: I want to automatize some stuff at my home, starting with the heating. To do this I looked at the [FHEM project](http://fhem.de/). All looks pretty good and interesting, but I realized quite early that I needed a small device to send and receive radio signals to all the devices of the house that I want to install.

The website suggested to [get this one](http://busware.de/tiki-index.php?page=CUL), but looking at the price it looked quite exagerated (plus the website does not look very reliable). Looking around on the internet I saw [this other item](http://www.amazon.de/Stable-Funk-Module-Technische-externer-Antenne/dp/B00GBW6WJY/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1418930738&sr=8-4&keywords=CUL). I am not very skilled when it comes to electrical things, but I could swear it is the exact same thing (Am I wrong??). the only difference I notice is that it does not have the USB jack solderer in. Fortunately I know someone that knows how to solder this kind of stuff. He agreed to help me with the project, but he told me he would need the schematics to figure out how to weld it.

Could someone please help me find those schematics, since I have no idea where to look for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those modules are similar in that they are both RF transceivers, but the second one (the CC1101 module) doesn't have the necessary capabilities built in to be able to 'talk USB' which the first one has.
Its not just a 'missing USB connector' and would need a bit more added on to be able to plug into a PC.

And just for future reference - welding vs soldering:  http://www.explainthatstuff.com/weldingsoldering.html
;)

Comment: I see. What is the second one missing to talk to the computer? Can you recommend me an alternative to the first one?

Answer (score 0):

The schematics for the CC1101 are available as part of the full schematics of the CUL 3.2 at http://busware.de/tiki-download_file.php?fileId=43. I too would be interested to know what 'extras' are required for the CC1101 to make it into a CUL 3.2.

Comment: I am guessing an Arduino nano or similar could be configured to be the 'extras'.